Closed linear span of unit standard vectors in $\ell^{p}$
$e_{n}$ is unit standard vector (unique non-zero entry is $1$ in the
coordinate $n$)
$\mathsf{c}_{0}$ is the space of all sequences converging to zero.
$\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is the set of sequences with finite support.
$\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is dense in $\ell^{p}$, $1\leq p<\infty$,
but$\ \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is not dense in $\ell^{\infty}$.
Are the following statements true?

the linear span of $\{e_{1},e_{2},\cdots\}$ is
$$
\mathrm{sp}(e_{1},e_{2},\cdots)=\mathbb{R}^{\infty}
$$

the closed linear span of $\{e_{1},e_{2},\cdots\}$ in $\ell^{p}$, $1\leq
p<\infty$, is
$$
\mathrm{csp}(e_{1},e_{2},\cdots)=\ell^{p}
$$

the closed linear span of $\{e_{1},e_{2},\cdots\}$ in $\ell^{\infty}$ is
$$
\mathrm{csp}(e_{1},e_{2},\cdots)=\mathsf{c}_{0}
$$


If all of the above are correct, then the closed linear span of the same set of
vectors may have different closed linear span for different space referred, right?

Yes, everything you said is right.
